# Prepositions relating to work: in, for, with and at

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

Are these sentences correct? If so, what do they mean?

I am working **in** IBM.

I am working **for** IBM.

I am working **with** IBM.

I am working **at** IBM.

Comment: This is the wrong question. The right question is what does each one mean.

Comment: @geeta, one of your tags is "meaning in context". Your question does not have a context. The context might be, for example,  "assume that  I am an employee of IBM".

Answer (score 4):

Prepositions tend to be very variable in usage: everyone has their own preferences. These are guidelines, not rules:

For a company, **in** does not really work. You could, however say

> I am working **in** the accounts department at IBM.

If you are an employee of the company, the best choice would be

> I work **for** IBM.

If you have been working for IBM a long time, you could also say

> I have been **with** IBM for 15 years.

If you are consultant or advisor, or you work for a company that is a business partner of IBM, you would say

> I work **with** IBM. - together with

If you are a builder and you are currently doing some work on the premises of the local IBM facility, you could say

> I work **at** IBM. - on the premises

Comment: I see *for* and *at* as interchangeable here, with the meaning of being an employee.